# Numpy install under Ubuntu (12.04) causes Python ImportError

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, importerror

Under Ubuntu (12.04), installed python (2.7.5) with numpy (1.8rc2) using openblas into own environment (/din).  The numpy site.cfg file is configured to point to openblas, and compiled as:

```
$ python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py install --prefix=/home/Programs/din/local

$ python

Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 24 2013, 15:33:08)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import numpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/Programs/din/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/home/Programs/din/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/Programs/din/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/home/Programs/din/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/Programs/din/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: 
"/home/Programs/din/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: ERR_peek_last_error
```

Cython, gevent, and other python packages have all been installed successfully into /din but not numpy.  The $PATH and python sys.path have been checked and all looks good.

Does anyone have ideas to try out?

Comment: ERR_peek_last_error points to a problem with your openssl installation. I suggest rebuilding openssl, since I don't think any of those other packages require it.

Comment: uhmm.  maybe have to perform an apt-get install libssl-dev? out of curiosity, how did you know it is an openssl installation problem?

Comment: ERR_peak_last_error is a part of openssl.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Re-built openssl but it generated the same error.  Also, tried with vanilla Numpy without blas/lapack but got the same error.

Answer (score 7):

This may not directly address your specific problem, but if you're on Ubuntu 12.04, you can just `apt-get`.  Then, because the version will not be the latest, I then do `pip install --upgrade`. Doing `apt-get` before `pip` first magically seems to install the right dependencies as well; if I do `pip install` first, it doesn't work.

Specifically:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy libblas-dev liblapack-dev gfortran python-dev
sudo pip install numpy --upgrade
sudo pip install scipy --upgrade
```