# Numpy on Python 3.3 on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, numpy

I tried installing numpy on Python 3.3 on Ubuntu 12.10

Following are the details of the Python implementation in case this is implementation specific.

```
Python 3.3.0 (default, Sep 29 2012, 17:17:45) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
```

So I ran the following at the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

which yields, [image]

But then, `import numpy` results in `ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`.

What am I doing wrong? Searching led me to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693302/numpy-install-under-ubuntu-12-04-causes-python-importerror) but as of now it has only 1 answer with no upvotes. Also the method mentioned there doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I suspect (so this is not an answer) that when you do an `apt-get` you will be updating the system python used by Ubuntu, which is probably 2.7 (or earlier).  You need to download numpy yourself and install it.  When you do that, make sure python 3.3 is in your PATH and you use `python setup.py install` rather than the `#!` line.

Comment: nobody? :( okay. *flies away*